# Answering questions from the comments

Tags: discussion

What would be the best practice?

#### You answered the question and then in the comments section of your answer you see another *non-related* question.

What do you recommend to do?

---

**I would define a *non-related* question as a completely different subject that deserves separate space.**

Comment: Who is the author of these quotes?

Comment: :) The quotes, I used for marking things better. The `stage` word I used to describe the situation, but again not a quote.

Comment: Please do not misuse quotes. There are better, more fitting formatting tools like headlines or lists. Quotes are just confusing.

Comment: Just realized that and I agree.

Comment: When this has happened to me in the past, I simply ask "how this question is related to my question" in a kind way. This normally kills it or brings something useful forward.

Comment: Too bad, I cannot set more than 1 upvote to your comment @ChristineCooper, but you deserve at least 10 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are usually meant for clarification and not for additional questions of extended discussion. If it is OP asking this question then the polite thing to do would be to ask if this solves their original issue and if they have a separate question to it in the same format as before. If it is not OP you can reply letting them know that the comment section is not for questions or you may report the comment as noise and we'll clean things up.

The important thing is to be polite and informative but also not pandering ( whether it is OP or not ) by also answering the question in comments.

Comment: Sorry, what is OP?

Comment: @prosti OP stands for Original Poster. In this case I'm referring to the Original Poster of the Question.